# How should I best react when questions are migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration

How can I prevent downvoting and loss of privileges in this community when questions are migrated here from another site and don't hold up to Code Reviews standards?

I want to be a participant in this community. It looks like an unexpectedly wonderful place to improve my craft and my value to clients. I am not ready to start posting code, as I haven't had the time to clean up any of my code prior to a public post (either to meet standards, or to comply with confidentiality). I would love to participate and help where I can too, but certainly don't have time for that right now.

So, in the meantime, how can I protect my profile and make sure that I don't lose rep and privileges here because of a migration I hadn't known about in advance? Not saying it was wrong (not saying that because I don't know the rules, not because I agree with it). I mean, I caught this one only a few days late, and hopefully no harm done (yet). At least one person thought it was a fit for the site, so I might leave it open for a bit longer before deleting... but what do I do in the future to make sure?

I think [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/a-question-was-migrated-to-cr-when-the-op-obviously-didnt-want-a-code-review-w) has some relevance to my question, but so far the only answer is 'that question and those like it are fair game', meaning that downvoting and losing rep because it doesn't meet site standards would be too. Right?

I suppose one answer would be 'Only post short succinct questions of high quality on the other sites that no one could possibly think should be migrated', and I will try to be there someday... but is that the only answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what advice to give, other than pointing out that under the [migration guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), "poorly-asked or non-constructive questions" are not supposed to be migrated in the first place. Of course, in practice, unexpected things happen.

Comment: @200_success Good point. It could be that this is an isolated incident, and I don't need to worry at all. I feel (could be wrong of course, outside of the scope of this question and CR itself) that the question that I have concerned myself with as posted on SO was sufficient, if not overly verbose. Once it was migrated to CR it becomes, I think, 'poorly asked' because of the pseudocode/non-working code, at least. Do you think it is ok to leave this meta question stand, though, in case this is not an isolated incident?

Comment: I didn't even see your [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128766/how-can-i-speed-up-search-across-text-files-to-faster-than-5-seconds) come in - and I troll VBA. What you should do here is take a look at our guidelines and improve the question so it fits better. If not, you can delete it or flag it as off-topic.

Comment: @Raystafarian Good point! One can only get so much from general policy questions. You also need to listen to specific members of your target market, in this case the actual people that will be volunteering their time to help me. Thank you. I won't be able to make worthwhile edits this weekend, but hopefully I can early next week.

Comment: I consider it a good question, because it's not an isolated incident.

Answer (score 5):

You could always delete questions which got migrated to another site, on that site, if they are off-topic or you are getting down-votes. That should not affect your site rep or stats after being deleted, granted you don't have too many of them.

Ideally one should read the on-topic page for a site before posting, but on occasion some unexpected migrations can happen. If in doubt, you can always flag for moderator attention and explain the reasoning.

Comment: Deleted downvoted posts count twice in the "good standing" calculation for question badges like 'curious'. Not sure how they affect the actual Q-ban standing, but they sure do affect it in some way only SE knows about.

Comment: Have enough posts removed in a period of time will get you Q-banned--even if you removed them yourself.  I know because I had it happen to me several years back--posted a question, found the answer, deleted the question, BAN!  Hadn't even earned any downvotes (or upvotes) on it.

Comment: @Hosch250 That is exactly what I am most worried about. I have never had that happen on any SE site, but I have lurked for long enough to know it is not something I am interested in experiencing... and that the reasoning behind these bans can often be murky (intentionally). I think we can all agree though, that if were to delete every question 'asked' (migrated) here before I ever asked and accepted an answer, it wouldn't be good. Again, as noted in original question, not planning on having this happen often, but want to be prepared.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks. At some point I will be interested in chasing badges and gaming the system (not going to lie, it's like keeping score and I like to win), but right now I just want to be seen as a (at least potentially) useful member of the community. I gather that, on most SE sites, rep and activity are better ways to show that than badges.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to catch the migration early enough, you should be able to do something before anyone down votes.

(I don't know if you get notified of migrations or not, but you should at least be monitoring your questions in case people leave comments.)

FYI, all down votes gotten before migration will be erased. I think up votes stay.

Deleted questions may count against you in some ways (one of the badges, for example). It might be worthwhile to delete, fix the code to be on topic, undelete, and edit the question.

Once you have a question that follows the rules, it's very likely that you will get a number of up votes.

You should relax a little `:)`. This site has a very calming atmosphere, and they are generous with up votes here.